# Build .jar from specified dependencies using maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I've got the maven-assembly-plugin working a treat, building a big fat .jar that includes my dependencies. Is there a way to build a .jar that only includes my project's code and a couple of specified dependencies, not the whole lot?

At the risk of being told "you're doing it wrong", my intention is to package up the code from only those projects that I manage, and distribute the managed dependencies separately, to be run by Hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the [Including and Excluding Artifacts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html), it mentions about the excludes as the following: -

```xml
<dependencySets>
  <dependencySet>
    ....
    <excludes>
      <exclude>commons-lang:commons-lang</exclude>
      <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </dependencySet>
  ....
</dependencySets>
```

I hope this may help.